# What is the accepted way to set UI properties when pushing a new VC?

Tags: ios

Let's say you're pushing a new View Controller onto the navigation stack and need to set a UI property (ex: a UI label's text or something). When you initialize the VC, it's views are not set (so they could be nil). Therefore, setting properties won't work. For example:

```
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
SomeViewController.someUILabel.text = @"foo";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

This won't set the UI label's text because vc.view and its subviews are nil. A couple of ways to remedy this are:

1. After calling `init` on the VC, do something like `[vc view]` which will load the view and then allow you to set properties.
2. Set a non-UI ivar and then in `viewDidLoad` set up the UI like so:

   ```
   SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init]; 
   SomeViewController.uiTextLabel = @"foo";
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
   // in viewDidLoad
   self.someUILabel.text = self.uiTextLabel
   ```

Is there an accepted way to get rid of this problem? Is one of these better than the other or is there a different solution?

Comment: Did you mean vc.someUILabel.text = @"foo"; ?

Comment: take nsstring property in second view controller and set it when push. and use that in secondviewcontroller to set text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the most elegant method to do this is:
in the main VC:

```
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
SomeViewController.textForLabel = @"foo";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

And in the pushed VC:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *textLabel;
@end

- (void)setTextForLabel:textForLabel
{
  _textForLabel = textForLabel;
  self.textLabel.text = self.textForLabel;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.textLabel.text = self.textForLabel;
}
```

So basically you set the property as an `NSString` and then adjust the UI in two separate places.

Answer (score 2):

You should not set the label value from another view controler. A controller controls its views.
You should have a `NSString` property in you `SomeViewController`, and set that public property instead with the string you want. Then, in `SomeViewController` `viewDidLoad` method set the value of the label to the one in the property.

Comment: How about if you're setting something else from another VC (ex an image URL) that has UI consequences. You would want to update the UI in the setter for the property, but it has the same problem unless the views are initialized, right?

Comment: @u_ser722345 No it's not the same problem. Of course when you set the property and the view is not initialized, the UI update won't work. But in your viewDidLoad method you will have your controller take the value of the property and update the UI accordingly. So there will be 2 UI updates. One called from viewDidLoad and the other one called from the setter of your property.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the views after pushing it in the stack and in the pushed vc not the one that pushed it.